# SVN history is lost in git

Tags: git, svn, move, revision-history

We moved a project from svn to git recently.
Before moving to git, some folders were re-organized in svn.

Now, git doesnt show the complete history for files in the folders that were moved/re-named in svn.

Any ideas how we can get git to show the complete history ? (--follow didnt help)

Comment: It depends on the kind of those folders: top-level like "branches/", "tags/", branches-level like "branches/xxx/" or "trunk/", or directories inside?

Comment: Basically Git doesn't work with directories at all, only with files. You can't track the directory history at all unless it corresponds to Subversion branch.

Comment: I had the same problem, by the way. I decided however that I don't care about that far in time back in my project's history.

Comment: @Dmitry: Yes. we want the file level history only. and sample re-org : a/trunk/b/c/code was re-organized to a/trunk/b/c/trunk/code

Answer (score 0):

Note that `git` does *not* store the history in any form, it only stores contents of files under their current names. It can (try to) reconstruct the history afterwards by looking for similar contents, that is all. It usually does a pretty good job at it, I might add.

This is a consciciuous decision on the part of the developers: If you get patches sent by mail, they don't carry a history around. And keeping that history locall requires messing with the tools (editor, `cp`, `mv`, ...) to really capture what is going on. It just isn't worth it.